# META-EQUIV Redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect, meta

I was wondering if it's possible to redirect

- http://9ui.co/r/example

to

- http://9ui.co/r.php?c=example

can I do it with meta-equiv, that would be way easier than .htaccess for server related reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Just check for a query string in the `index.php`:

```
if (count($_GET) > 0)
  echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL= http://9ui.co/r.php?' . http_build_query($_GET) . '">';
```

If you want the code to be W3C Compliant, you can use this instead:

```
http_build_query($_GET, '', '&amp;');
```

Comment: When I use it it tries to redirect the webpage to itself therefore rendering it useless

Comment: What goes between the single quotes?

Comment: The `http_build_query($_GET)` will send the `$_GET` same way as it is got in the main page. So, that would transfer it to your new page. Play around with it, coz you know the coding.